# THE TARGET MACHINE IS NOT JOINED TO A DOMAN

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server, adfs3.0

I am trying to install **Active Directory Federation Services** on Windows Server 2012 but I keep getting this error:

> THE TARGET MACHINE IS NOT JOINED TO A DOMAN

[image: error message]

On the top you can see TARGET SERVER has my server name. Why am I getting this error? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Federation Services is a feature you can add to an already-existing Active Directory domain. So you need a domain already setup, and the server already joined to that domain to be able to install Federation Services.

If you are trying to create a new AD domain, then you need to install Active Directory Domain Services. Instructions are here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12370.windows-server-2012-set-up-your-first-domain-controller-step-by-step.aspx